# exit condition of repeadly accepting input from STDIN

Tags: c

i'm reading a string from STDIN

```
    unsigned char arr[200];
    gets(arr);
  // do something with arr
```

above code will excute once.

Now i wanted to allow user to input multiple string from STDIN using loop. And also some option to exit if user do not want to enter more string.

like:

```
while(CONDITION){
   gets(arr);
   // do something with arr
}
```

How can i put some condition like this ?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `gets()`, it's dangerous, use `fgets()` instead.

`fgets()` returns a null pointer when end-of-file is encountered, or when a read error occurs.  And it returns a non-null pointer when read successfully. You can use this return value as the condition.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead of `gets`. Secondly, if you read the linked reference of `fgets` you will know it returns a non-null pointer is everything is okay, and so you can use that as your loop condition.

Answer (score 0):

may be like this

```
while(1) {
 gets(arr);
 if(someExitCondition(arr))
  break;
 // do something with arr
}
```

ofcouse use fgets instead of gets

Answer (score 0):

You can do as,

```
 while((fgets(arr, sizeof arr, stdin) != NULL))
 {  
     // do something with arr
 }
```

Since you are using [fgets()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) for first time, its syntax is,

```
char * fgets ( char * str, int num, FILE * stream );
```

1. `str` is `char *` where your input is stored.
2. `num` is the maximum number of characters to read
3. `stream` is a pointer to a`FILE` structure, that returned from fopen.
    stdin, stdout, and stderr as well.